# Loop on directories using a batch file and paste folders

Tags: loops, batch-file

Consider that I have this structure:

```
E:
-- /Company/
----/- Migrations -/
------/- All environments/
--------/A/
--------/B/
--------/C/
--------/D/
```

And I want to copy a folder for example (E:\Company\folder) into all the folders inside "- All environments" so into folders A,B,C and D. I however am stuck at looping on the folders and haven't got the the point where I can copy the folder yet.

This is my current code

```
FOR /D %i  in ("E:\Company\- Migrations -\- All environments\*") DO ECHO %i
```

I'm expecting to echo the names of the folders, however nothing is coming out, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual after searching for 2 hours without finding an answer, I have found it right after putting this question.

The correct syntax is

```
FOR /D %%i  in ("E:\Company\- Migrations -\- All environments\*") DO ECHO %%i
```

Comment: @V-SHY : from the prompt, use single `%`. Within a batch file, double `%` is required.

Comment: thanks, learn new things. Refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634 , "if there are no characters between the two percent signs, one percent sign is stripped off and the other will remain. This is why a FOR command that echos the name of each file with a .COM extension would be
   FOR %V IN (*.COM) DO ECHO %V
    
but if the same command is placed in a batch file, the following is required:
   FOR %%V IN (*.COM) DO ECHO %%V"